# How to pass param to Graph API nested query (Facebook API)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to write a nested query for Facebook graph API to get my stores info with metrics.

I can get this insight like:

```
story_id/insights?metric=navigation&breakdown=story_navigation_action_type
```

But how to do that in nested query?

I've tried:

```
user_id/stories?fields=id,ig_id,media_type,caption,owner,media_url,shortcode,timestamp,thumbnail_url,insights.metric(navigation)&breakdown=story_navigation_action_type
```

And result is just a number without breakdown. I also tried:

```
user_id/stories?fields=id,ig_id,media_type,caption,owner,media_url,shortcode,timestamp,thumbnail_url,insights.metric(navigation.breakdown(story_navigation_action_type))"
```

And got an error.

Comment: Have you tried `insights.metric(navigation).breakdown(story_navigation_action_type)`?

Comment: @AlexZaitsev could you please share the GET request that worked for you? I am not getting the breakdown at all

my query: 

GET https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/<USER_ID>/stories?fields=caption,media_type,ig_id,id,like_count,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,shortcode,video_title,username,timestamp,media_product_type,owner,children,insights.metric(impressions,reach,replies,navigation).breakdown(story_navigation_action_type)&access_token=TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{ig-media-id}/insights
  ?metric={metric}
  &breakdown={breakdown}
  &access_token={access-token}
```

In your case, it should be structure liked this.

```
story_ID/insights?metric={navigation}&breakdown={story_navigation_action_type}&access_token={your-access-token}
```

Here's the documentation link for the above reference.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights/